# getResource and getResourceAsStream return null

Tags: java, resources

My program consists of two files:

```
package net.sf.junace.demo;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.io.File;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalIconFactory;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class Manager extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JTextField textField;
    private JPanel panel;
    private JScrollPane scrollPanel;
    private JTable table;

    public Manager(String string) {
        super(string);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout(2, 2));

        textField = new JTextField(10);
        panel.add(textField, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        String[] columnNames = { "Name", "Size", "Modified" };
        File[] filesAndDirs = new File(".").listFiles();
        Object[][] data = new Object[filesAndDirs.length][3];
        for (int i = 0; i < filesAndDirs.length; i++) {
            data[i][0] = filesAndDirs[i].getName();
            data[i][1] = filesAndDirs[i].length();
            Date date = new Date(filesAndDirs[i].lastModified());
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss");
            data[i][2] = sdf.format(date);
        }
        table = new JTable(data, columnNames);

        table.getTableHeader().getColumnModel().getColumn(0)
                .setCellRenderer(new IconRenderer(filesAndDirs));
        scrollPanel = new JScrollPane(table);
        panel.add(scrollPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(panel);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    protected static void createAndShowGUI() {
        Manager frame = new Manager("Manager");
    }
}
```

and second:

```
package net.sf.junace.demo;

import java.awt.Component;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;

public class IconRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
    File[] files;
    // URL url;
    ImageIcon folderIcon;

    public IconRenderer(File[] files) {
        super();
        this.files = files;
        // THIS not works
        // InputStream in =
        // getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/folder16.png");
        // URL url = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/folder16.png");
        // folderIcon = new ImageIcon(url);

        // THIS works fine
        folderIcon = new ImageIcon("d:\\code\\proj.git\\Ikony\\folder16.png");

    }

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object obj,
            boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, obj, isSelected, hasFocus,
                row, column);
        if (files[row].isDirectory())
            setIcon(folderIcon);
        setBorder(UIManager.getBorder("TableHeader.cellBorder"));
        return this;
    }
}
```

This show list files and directories. Directories must have icon. This example works with directory:

```
folderIcon = new ImageIcon("d:\\code\\proj.git\\Ikony\\folder16.png");
```

But I want place file `folder16.png` in project directory and in future in `.jar`. Not works getResource and getResourceAsStream:

```
InputStream in = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/folder16.png");
```

returns `null`.

```
URL url = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/folder16.png");
```

also returns `null`, regardless where I place `folder16.png`: in root project directory or in the `src` subdirectory.

Comment: `jLabel1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/com/javaquery/icon_128.png")));` try like this

Comment: I think you should check if `folder16.png` is in the folder that contains classes

Comment: Place `folder16.png` in the default package (root) of the `src` folder.

Comment: I have placed in src\ root and getResource("/folder16.png")) but still error. I have placed full source of my small example, why not works?

Answer (score 0):

You should put it together with the Java source file of the class that requires the file. Then you should use [Class.getResource(String name)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) or [Class.getResourceAsStream(String name)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29). In other words, you should skip the `getClassLoader()` call.

You don't need the full path name to the file, it is automatically prepended before the name by the above methods. It is better to use `IconRenderer.class` instead of `getClass()` as there is no need to determine the class at runtime. If you do then classes that extend your class may fail.

Comment: Why do you say it is _probably better_? `getClass()` is independent of the class name or location.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis good question, I'll make it just `better` :)

Comment: I don't agree with you. If you refactor the class name, you have to change that code too. You don't have to with `getClass()`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Eclipse seems to handle that kind of refactoring just fine. And it gets a bit trickier if you create a child class - `getClass()` will point to the new class - possibly in another package - if I'm not mistaken. In that case the class should at least be `protected` or `final`. The class definition is specific to the package, so is the resource. There is no need for runtime determination of the class.

Comment: I try folderIcon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/net/sf/junace/demo/folder16.png"));
and not works - NullPointerException

Comment: Ah, no, read the method documentation, you don't need the full path, try just `"folder16.png"`. Edited this into the answer.

Comment: But is OK, if I folder16.png place to bin\ directory with .class! This is maybe obvious, because distributed version is .class, not .java, but I have git, ignore bin\ directory but not ignoring resources?

Comment: Your resource should be copied from the src/package folder to the class/package folder when you perform the compilation to class files. If you are using an IDE, don't forget to clean and rebuild, and make sure that the resource file is copied correctly.

Comment: If I have in .class directory is OK, if I have in Jave directory - not. Build with Eclipse previously not copied, but If I refresh project (F5), png appears in project and copied if I first call project clean. Now Is OK! In code is folderIcon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("folder16.png"));

Comment: Glad you have got it working! Make sure you switch on autobuild. You may want to check for Eclipse answers if the file is not copied when you expect it should. Note that eclipse does not poll the folder contents continuously. If you add files using e.g. Windows explorer then it won't notice new files until you refresh. Dragging stuff into the Eclipse Navigator or Package Explorer view should work though.

Comment: Why not accept the answer, Borneq, is there still anything wrong with it?